# Pentaho - How to pass result-set (TableModel ) from xaction to prpt

Tags: pentaho, tablemodel, xaction

I have an issue with pass result-set from xaction to prpt.

When I use a example prpt then modify it, the report is ok.

But when I create a new prpt (datasource: External, a TableModel type parameter is same as the first one)  it does work, just prints out labels, miss the data.

Did I miss something?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. Click attribute of 'Master Report' on the Structure panel.
Find query - name, add the value as the name of result set.